# Workbook_SheetSelectionChange() dramaticly slowing down scrolling in large spreadsheet

Tags: excel, windows, performance, events

If I add the following VBA function to ThisWorkbook in Excel, then I find scrolling around the spreadsheet becomes very slow and jerky. It is a large 50 sheet / 50MB spreadsheet with a lot of vlookup() type calls in it, as well as array formulae {}. Even if I comment out the one line of code, scrolling around the spreadsheet is still very slow. If I comment out the entire Sub, then I get normal scrolling. I am trying to monitor when the user last did something to the spreadsheet.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    LastUserActivity = Now()
End Sub
```

Any idea what may be going on?

Comment: When you say the 'user last did something' ... do you mean changed the sheet's values, or just navigated around? Do you want the `Workbook_SheetChange()` event instead?

Comment: Workbook_SheetChange() doesn't slow things down in the same way, and so is a very helpful second best. But ideally I'd like to just know when the user presses a key anywhere in the spreadsheet so I know someone is doing something and the  spreadsheet isn't completely idle. It baffles me that such a tiny function can cause such a performance change!

Comment: Actually unfortunately Workbook_SheetChange() doesn't work since there is a VBA routine working in the background which makes occasional changes to the sheet triggering this event. Any other ideas? Or why Workbook_SheetSelectionChange() slows thing down so much?